# How to write quadratic equation on Label in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, statistics

We are making statistical software. Everywhere we need to put formula such as `ax2+bx+c` How to make `ax2` means x square 2. I want to display 2 on upper side of x. Same with πc I want to display c at suffix.

Comment: Use Charmap.exe to find the glyphs you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a fixed list of formulas that users can choose but cannot edit? Then generate an image for each formula, store them in your application, and display them in a `PictureBox`.

If you expect users to be able to type in arbitrary formulas and render them interactively, you will have to implement a visual [formula editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor) control. These controls take markup such as MathML or TeX and render them as graphics. Several are described in the link I provided, but I do not know of any such .Net controls for WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

for the "upper" 2 and 3 there are symbols: a², a³ (even on a german keyboard but you will find them in your symboltable in windows too) - the lower c will be harder - I would consider using pictures for those more complex formulas (if you need dynamic formulas it you might have to create them with Graphics in code)