# display equations in windows form desktop application in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have searched for displaying equations in windows form desktop application in c#. 
I know we can do it using MimeTex, or LaTeX .
Does anyone knows bit easy and lighter method making use of label or rich textbox or similar to represent equations ?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409695/how-to-write-quadratic-equation-on-label-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: I dont want to use picturebox as it would be a heavier application as I have many equations to be shown.. Also using symbols(from charmap) for subscript or superscript doesnt fulfills my purpose.

Comment: This [article](http://cmiles.info/2009/10/03/some-experiences-in-the-display-of-mathematical-equations-in-wpf/) might help you.

Comment: You can also use [Math Expression Editor](http://othercontrols.com/en/products/mathexpressioneditorlight/). But it's **not free**.

Comment: Thannks Jowie. I will get back after implementation of best from above methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try out the following,

1. Host a WebBrowser control
2. Create HTML element with [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render your equations.

It's not perfect, but at least should work.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li..    I did not use MathJax, but MS word. I made a Word file with equations and saved it as .html  The path of this file is given in WebBrowser control property "URL". I can see the equations on form load.

Comment: I think that's even easier than what I suggested.